# Class method does not run when called upon in Kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am new to kivy.
I have created a login page with 2 text fields. I am now trying to pass the variables to the next page, which will use a ssh client for python to connect to a server. However, when I run the program, it seems that the method I am calling in my second screen does not even run, as none of the debugging output shows up.

I have tried a few methods of passing in variables into a function of a different class, and temporarily I have set upon using global variables. I am sure there is an easier or better way, but I can't get the function to run in the first place.

main.py

```py
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)

from kivy.app import App

from kivy.properties import StringProperty

from kivy.core.window import Window

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition

import csv
import paramiko
#import os

global username
global password

def load_csv(filepath):
    with open(filepath, newline='') as csvfile:
        file_array = list(csv.reader(csvfile))
        csvfile.close()
    return file_array

class Connect(Screen):
    Window.size = (600, 300)
    def routine(self):

        host = 'titanrobotics.ddns.net'
        port = 60022
        print(username, password)
        self.ids.status.text = "connecting"

        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

        try:
            self.ids.status.text = "attempting to connect to " + host
            ssh.connect(host, port, username, password)
            yield ssh
            self.ids.status.text = "connected to " + host

        finally:
            ssh.close()
            self.ids.status.text = "connection failed"

        #print("here")
    #ssh = loginroutine(username, password)

class Login(Screen):
    Window.size = (600, 300)
    def do_login(self, loginText, passwordText):
        app = App.get_running_app()

        username = loginText
        password = passwordText

        self.manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction = "left")
        self.manager.current = "connect"

    def resetForm(self):
        self.ids['login'].text = ""
        self.ids['password'].text = ""

class BrummetApp(App):
    username = StringProperty(None)
    password = StringProperty(None)

    title = 'Brummet Client v ' + load_csv("data/meta")[0][1]

    def build(self):
        manager = ScreenManager()

        manager.add_widget(Login(name = 'login'))
        manager.add_widget(Connect(name = 'connect'))

        return manager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    BrummetApp().run()
```

brummet.kv

```
<Login>:
    BoxLayout
        id: login_layout
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: [10,10,10,10]
        spacing: 10

        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'vertical'
            padding: [0,0,0,0]
            spacing: 0

            Label:
                id: title
                text: 'Brummet Client'
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'middle'
                font_size: 24

            Label:
                text: 'Please log in with IMSA SLURM credentials'
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'middle'
                spacing: -20
                font_size: 24

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'

            Label:
                text: 'Username'
                font_size: 18
                halign: 'left'
                text_size: root.width-20, 0

            TextInput:
                id: username
                multiline: False
                font_size: 16
                write_tab: False

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                text: 'Password'
                halign: 'left'
                font_size: 18
                text_size: root.width-20, 0

            TextInput:
                id: password
                multiline: False
                password: True
                font_size: 16
                write_tab: False

        Button:
            text: 'Log In'
            font_size: 24

            on_press:
                root.do_login(username.text, password.text)

<Connect>:
    on_enter:
        root.routine()
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: [0,125,0,125]
        spacing: 0

        Label:
            text:'Logging In'
            font_size: 24
            halign: 'center'
            valign: 'middle'

        Label:
            id: status
            test:''
            font_size: 16
            halign: 'center'
            valign: 'middle'
```

It seems that loading the Connect class is fine, however I am unable to run the .routine() method on_enter.

Comment: Try print something else than username and password. Just "test" or whatever

Comment: i tried putting print statements after each line, nothing within the function printed out

Comment: Using `yield` in `routine()` makes it a generator function. Is that your intent?

Comment: I guess I should be clearer. When you call a generator function, it does not execute the function code, but returns an iterator that, when called, will execute the original function code.

Comment: I didn't even notice the yield statement when I copied that bit from a previous not working project. I removed it and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `yield ssh` is preventing the `Connect.routine()` from executing. Try comment it off.